# how to initialise java object from kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I want to initialize object from java class in Kotlin class.

I have java class Car for 
example `com.myapp.vehicles.car`

in java I would do

```
buss = new car()
```

then call `buss.drive()`

how do I do same from kotlin.

I have tried `var buss = car.getinstance()`
but there is no method `getinstance`

Comment: just `var buss = car()`

Comment: yes i tried to find answer forexample https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getInstance()` method created by itself for initialization.

in Java

```
buss = new car()
call =buss.drive()
```

In kotlin

```
var buss = car()
var method = buss.drive()
```

Comment: because this question is bad and by answering it you encourage more of such questions to be posted

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin no need to `new` world so just type this for new instance of class

```
var buss = car()
```

Now you can use all object and function of `car` class

Also i suggest use Uppercase for start letter of your classes

Comment: kotlin has no new keyword, you're looking for `var buss = car()`

Comment: @a_local_nobody you right, my bad! too fast copy paste without edit makes that mistake